# <input accept="image/tif does not show *.tif files

Tags: html, input, internet-explorer-11, tiff

I have the following HTML tag:

```
<input id="inputButton" name="buttonAdd" type="file" class="upload" accept="image/bmp, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png, image/tif, image/tiff, application/pdf" multiple/>
```

When I click on the button to select a file to upload, the available file types are initially filtered, as expected. The filter does show files with a *.TIFF extension, but it does not show files having only *.TIF extension (see the attached screenshot)

[image: .tif files are missing from the filter]

I am using Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 and I MUST ALSO enable the functionality for *.TIF files.

Could somebody help me?

[image: .*TIFF files showed, but *TIF files - not]

Comment: Try adding `image/tiff-fx`? `image/*`? If that doesn't work, you can always do: `accept="image/bmp, ... , image/tif, .tif"` - you can specify file extensions instead of MIME types.

Comment: @AurelBílý thanks, adding .tif, did the job!

Comment: Submitted as an answer if you'd like to accept :)

Answer (score 2):

> `accept`
>
> If the value of the type attribute is `file`, then this attribute will indicate the types of files that the server accepts, otherwise it will be ignored. The value must be a comma-separated list of unique content type specifiers:
>
> - A file extension starting with the STOP character (U+002E). (e.g. .jpg, .png, .doc).
> - A valid MIME type with no extensions.
> - [...]
>
> [Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept)

So in your case, you can do:

```
<input id="inputButton" name="buttonAdd" type="file" class="upload"
  accept="image/bmp, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png, image/tif,
  image/tiff, application/pdf, .tif" multiple/>
```